# adding like button next to each list item ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a like button next to a list of 'destinations'. however, I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to place a button right next to each list item. any help???

Here is my dashboard.html.erb file:

```
<div class="destination-list">
    <h1>Destinations</h1>
    <table id="destTable">


     <tr class="table-initial">
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>Address:</td>

            <span class="likebtn-wrapper" data-white_label="true" data-identifier="item_1" data-show_dislike_label="true" data-popup_disabled="true" data-share_enabled="false"></span>
            <script>(function(d,e,s){if(d.getElementById("likebtn_wjs"))return;a=d.createElement(e);m=d.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];a.async=1;a.id="likebtn_wjs";a.src=s;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)})(document,"script","//w.likebtn.com/js/w/widget.js");</script>

        <!-- <td>Delete:</td> -->
     </tr>


    </table>

    <div class="big create">+</div>
</div>

<div class="submit">

    <h1>Create Destination</h1>
    <form method="get" action="index.html" class="form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name-input" name="name" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Address" class="address-input" name="address" />
                    <input type="submit" class="submit-input my-button" id="create-button"></input>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your source parameter in your javascript function call is missing the `http:` protocol part.

You should edit the tags in your question, though. Your code shows no Rails or Ruby, and your question is purely about Javascript.

On a side note, you should look up **unobtrusive javascript** :

[Rails guides](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwilmoq-5PfIAhWEXhoKHUi8CFw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fedgeguides.rubyonrails.org%2Fworking_with_javascript_in_rails.html&usg=AFQjCNFczzJNHFUE19OaKVcxghgy11LSng&sig2=IjffDSElb8wSoiyg8-_BXw&bvm=bv.106674449,d.d2s)

[RailsCasts episode](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwilmoq-5PfIAhWEXhoKHUi8CFw&url=http%3A%2F%2Frailscasts.com%2Fepisodes%2F205-unobtrusive-javascript&usg=AFQjCNHXOCORw-It-CE0tEg1joqGq7YIYA&sig2=YxovgkeHqkheNRMV3_QiZg&bvm=bv.106674449,d.d2s)

and probably jQuery as well.

Comment: So, keeping unobtrusive javascript in mind, should I create a new file with just the creation of a button?

Comment: In general, yes. Ideally, you want to keep your JS and your HTML separate, and include your JS file (using a `<script>` tag) in your HTML file just before the closing `</body>` tag.
If you're trying to add a social network 'like' button, though, it might be easier to follow the implementation guidelines for that particular social network (those can usually be found on their website's developers section).